# Suggestion for a lot of chained Task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a lot of `Task` continuation that depend on `.Result` of previous `Task` -> for example: I have a *command* that should:

1. Stop previous instance
2. Copy files elsewhere
3. Delete original files
4. Start instance again

So for example the *command* function:

```
public Task<CommandResult> Execute(ICommandArguments arguments)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<CommandResult> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<CommandResult>();

    // 1. Stop
    var tskStop = this.stopCommand.Execute(arguments);
    tskStop.ContinueWith(stoppingTask =>
    {
        if (stoppingTask.Result == CommandResult.Success)
        {
           // 2. Copy files
           var tskCopy = this.copyCommand.Execute(arguments);
           tskCopy.ContinueWith(copyingTask =>
           {
               if (copyingTask.Result == CommandResult.Success)
               {
                  // 3. Delete
                  ... skip for brevity...
               }
               else
               {
                  // Could not 'delete'
                  tcs.SetResult(CommandResult.Fail);
                }
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion | TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);

            tskCopy.ContinueWith(tskCopyBad =>
            {
               //Error in 'copy'
               tcs.SetException(tskCopyBad.Exception.Flatten());
             }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion | TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
         }
         else
         {
            // Could not 'stop' for some reason
            tcs.SetResult(stoppingTask.Result);
          }
      }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion | TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);

      tskStop.ContinueWith(tskSTopBad =>
      {
           // Exception in 'stop'
           tcs.SetException(tskStopBad.Exception.Flatten());
      }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion | TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
}
```

and you see that only with 2 'commands' code blown to so many lines. Is there any design pattern, shortcut, or extension that I can add/use to shorten code lines? I depend on the `.Result` from the previous `Task` and its `Status` (to know whether an exception was thrown or not).

Note that we currently develop our app in .NET 4 so we are limited to `Task`, and unfortunately cannot use `async`/`await`.

P.S. All those `copyCommand`, `deleteCommand` is also have a `public Task<CommandResult> Execute()` function

Comment: You can use async/await with .NET 4: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2012/10/22/using-asyncawait-without-net-framework-4-5/

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - Cool package but currently we can not just throw in additional libraries :( There's no time to re-write this tested code :(

Comment: But you're talking about rewriting code already @Jasper.

Comment: yes - sorry. I mean rewrite with async/await. I do understand that I need to refactor this code - but prefer to stay with `Task`

Comment: Are the `// 1. Stop`, `// 2.  Copy files`, etc. comments actually in your code? Also note, `... skip for brevety...` isn't ideal on this site - we prefer (by far) reviewing your *actual* code, so when you get feedback like "these comments should be removed" you don't have to explain that "yeah but *my real actual code doesn't have them*". And if the `...skipped...` part stands for 20 lines of code, by removing it you probably prevented a reviewer from suggesting a refactoring.

Comment: Is there some particular reason that you've modelled it as a "copy" followed by a "delete" rather than just a "Move"?

Comment: This code won't compile (ignoring "... skip for brevity..."), so I've voted to close the question as off-topic.

Comment: @RobH - yes - there's a reason

Comment: @mjolka - yes - this code is not _real_ code - for example in case of exception it loggin it to file - but I didn't included logging facilities because it would complicate the code that already complicated. My question was about syntax of `Task` continuation process - it does not matter if this code compiles - the question is about syntax

Comment: @mjolka - may be we should move this question to programmers.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what is on- or off-topic at programmers.se, so I'm afraid I can't give any advice on moving it there.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to get away from chaining a ton of `ContinueWith` invocations together. However, you might be able to create a builder class with methods that you pass parameters to so you don't have to call `ContinueWith` from calling code.

It looks like you might be able to remove a lot of duplication by extracting your anonymous methods into one or more stateless (probably static) methods that you can reuse by passing the method signature in, e.g.

```
private static void SetFlattenedException(Task stoppedTask, TaskContinuationOptions options)
```

You can also start going down the route of wrapping continuations in method calls with additional `Action` parameters to "inject" code to execute, but given that it tends to lead to a lot of "inside-out" code that is hard to follow, I'd use sparingly.